# Group action $GL(m,\mathbb{R}) \times GL(n,\mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

I've got some questions about an exercise. We consider $\mathcal{M}_{m \times n}(\mathbb{R})$ and $GL(m,\mathbb{R}) \times GL(n,\mathbb{R})$, and the action of group given by : $(P,Q).A = PAQ^{-1}$.

The first question is to determine the orbits. So, obviously, if $A=0$, then $\mathcal{O}_A = \{0 \}$. Now, I wanted to show that if $A$, $B$ has the same rank, then $B \in \mathcal{O}_A$. I try to think with the linear functions and determine two linear function which would permit to conclude, but I didn't succeed to do that. Actually, I got lost on my calculations...

Then, we suppose $m \leq n$, and we want to determine the stabilizer of $(\; I_m \, | \, 0 \;)$. And again, I get lost on my calculations, mainly because I think I should use block matrix multiplication, and I'm really bad when it's start with such things...

Someone could help me, please ?

Thank you !

Comment: Do you know that every matrix is equivalent to a matrix that looks like $I_n$ but with $0$'s replacing the $1$'s after dome point ?

Comment: Finally (i've deleted my previous comment), it's okay ! So, for the first question, it's alright, thank you !